# Could we please have an ng-bootstrap Slider?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Is there any chance of an [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) slider please? I keep finding that I need it and having to go elsewhere for an implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a feature request. The place for it is here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

Comment: It is a feature request for a specific library